# Spring Boot Actuator Micrometer New Relic Integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, newrelic, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I want to use New Relic, using the micrometer support of the spring boot actuator.
I am not using agents.
I have a configuration as below.
I can see data in data explorer (event or metric etc.) However, I can't see anything in the APM section of the explorer page.

1. Is there a root cause of this due to the configuration, maybe something I missed?
2. I think I don't have to use agents because I use Micrometer, am I right?
3. Is it really a problem that I can't see anything in the APM section of the explorer page, would it come up automatically in a proper integration?

Thanks.

**application.yaml**

```
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      newrelic:
        api-key: ${MY_API_KEY}
        account-id: ${MY_ACCOUNT_ID}
        step: 3s
        uri: ${URI}
        meter-name-event-type-enabled: true
        enabled: true
logging:
  level:
    io:
      micrometer:
        newrelic: TRACE
```

**console**

```
i.m.n.NewRelicInsightsApiClientProvider  : successfully sent 75 metrics to New Relic
```

**dependencies**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-new-relic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

References:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.export.newrelic

https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/new-relic

Answer (score 0):

New Relic uses a Synthesis engine to create "Entities"; and in the opensource [entityDefinition repository](https://github.com/newrelic/entity-definitions/blob/f42d57be2de543d748e51a97bb78d7335d01049f/definitions/ext-service/definition.yml) it looks like you need to make sure you have an attribute/tag value specified for `service.name`.